# 17.10 file explorer app Files 3.26.0 fails to recognize mouse middle button to lower window

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, 17.10

It's very handy to send any open Ubuntu window to below all other open windows (it says open yet now occluded) by clicking mouse middle button on window title bar (opposite of left mouse click to bring to focus front) ... this fails on Ubuntu 17.10's new file explorer called Files 3.26.0 which has a non-standard looking title bar.

This behavior continues to be OK on all other 17.10 applications... Nautilus worked OK, but it looks like it's no longer the default file manager... I hope other apps refrain from using this new window behavior

I have nautilus installed and on launch it becomes Files 3.26.0 exhibiting this bad behavior... Nautilus works fine on Ubuntu 17.04 and earlier

Any ideas on why Files breaks this convention? Or how to fix it?

Comment: What's the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar`?

Comment: it outputs  
'lower'

Comment: not in Wayland session ... loginctl show-session    c2  -p Type ... output  
Type=x11

Comment: it works just fine on every app except Files 3.26.0 windows

Comment: `"I do not know the relationship between Files and nautilus "` Files is just the displayed name of Nautilus & has been for a while now.  You must not have been paying attention before. Shade has been disabled in 17.10 due to poor or non performance

Comment: Although Ubuntu 17.10 was released officially, this still sounds like a bug report or feature request to me.

Comment: I think it's about time to kiss middle-click-on-title-bar-to-lower-windows feature goodbye. With the implementation of [GtkHeaderBar](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkHeaderBar.html) and client-side decoration in general separate title bars for windows will probably die out. So that feature will not going to be the same again.